# Adding a favicon to a Chrome Extension new tab page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension loads main.html as the new tab page. How do I specify a favicon for that page?

When I try to specify a favicon in main.html, it doesn't appear. Here's my code in the `<head>` section:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico">
```

There is a 16px icon specified in the manifest, but it doesn't appear as the favicon:

```
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
                     "32": "icon32.png",
                     "128": "icon128.png" }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you load the resource directly via `chrome-extension://…/main.html`, the icon is shown in the tab, but not in the new tab page. This seems to be deliberate, see [favicon::ShouldDisplayFavicon in browser/favicon/favicon_utils.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=symbol:favicon::ShouldDisplayFavicon+f:cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs).

There's no obvious way around this without e.g. manually setting the tab URL to the `chrome-extension://` scheme, which would not work well as a new tab page.

Comment: Looks pretty clear from that code that it is indeed impossible... Oh well.

Comment: For future readers, it seems that this is now possible. [Screenshot of a recent update](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/mriblu/so_chromes_new_tab_page_now_has_a_proper_favicon/)